# Is it important for reflection-based serialization maintain consistent field ordering?

Tags: java, packet, code-reflection

I just finished writing a packet builder that dynamically loads data into a data stream for eventual network transmission. Each builder operates by finding fields in a given class (and its superclasses) that are marked with a `@data` annotation.

When I finishing my implementation, I remembered that `getFields()` [does not return results in any specific order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29).

Should reflection-based methods for serializing arbitrary data (like my packets) attempt to preserve a specific field ordering (such as alphabetical), and if so, how?

Comment: I tweaked the wording of your question to attempt to make it more broadly applicable, and less localized to your specific implementation.

Comment: I declined the suggested off-topic close vote; yes, on the surface this is not about games, but the requirements of and best way to deal with serialization for game networking is different than what I would recommend for HPC or Web interfaces.  I would answer this question differently here than I would on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch and off-topic-suggesters: It was originally about packet handler for a game. Josh edited and generalized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system can *deserialize* the data on the other end regardless of the field order, you don't *need* to enforce that order. But you probably want to anyway, because it's better.

If you have any dependency on that ordering (as in, you enumerate the results of `getFields()` on the receiving end and deserialize each field in succession), you had best make sure you have control over it, or you will end up tracking down a very subtle-looking bug a long way in the future. Then you'll really kick yourself. This is the most important reason to order the fields, but it will also be useful for a programmer to know the expected ordering when he or she works on the system, or its data.

There are a few downsides to some ordering methods. They have the potential to introduce diffs within the middle of the serialized data, which can make versioning a chore (append-only versioning is much easier to deal with). If you can guarantee that you won't interoperate data between versions, this is less of a concern.

It's usually hard to get reflection APIs to return results in code-declaration order. So any ordering method (alphabetical, size, name hash, whatever) will have some disconnect with the layout of the structure as read by a programmer. At least with a defined, enforced  ordering you know what that disconnect will be. The ordering of `getFields` shouldn't be relied on and could potentially change underneath you when you least expect it.

Comment: The advantage to a consistent ordering is that your serialization can be smaller.  Deserialization is just "get next value" rather than "find out what the next value is for, then get it" - which probably won't matter on a smaller scale but absolutely matters in the AAA space.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I guess I'll go to an alphabetical sorting, despite the disconnect between code-order and runtime-order (would be so nice if java returned in declaration order, for super-most class down, or similar), but I guess I can't have everything.